# Is there any difference between GraphQL on Experience Edge vs the XM / XM Cloud Edge Preview endpoints?

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud, experience-edge

Is there any functional, behavioural, or schema differences between GraphQL on the [Experience Edge API](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/210/sitecore-headless-development/the-experience-edge-schema.html) vs the Sitecore Platform XM or XM Cloud [Edge Preview endpoint](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/210/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-experience-edge-for-xm-preview-graphql-endpoint.html)?

Answer (score -1):

There are no functional or schema differences between the two. There is one potential behavioural difference in that the query complexity is calculated differently so this max complexity settings may need to be adjusted. This is described further [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/210/sitecore-headless-development/graphql-security.html).

Comment: The URL is fetched differently and the edge graphql does not have standard Sitecore fields like updated date, revision number, etc.